# Add 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session': ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I want to integrate the 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session' package into my aspnetboilerplate solution (ASP.NET Core 2.x) to use sessions.

I add the 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session' package to my Web.Mvc project via NuGet. Then I insert the following code into `ConfigureServices` method (Startup.cs):

```
    // Session Configuration
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
        options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder { HttpOnly = true };
    });
```

After that I call `app.UseSession()` after `app.UseAbp()` in the `Configure` method (Startup.cs).

Now, if I run the application, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel - Connection id "0HL96OHPL754P",
>   Request id "0HL96OHPL754P:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown
>   by the application. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: key    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.RequestCookieCollection.get_Item(String
>   key)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext()

If I remove `app.UseSession()` call, the application runs correctly.

Any ideas? Please help!

Comment: Could you try specifying the name of the cookie in CookieBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Thanks juunas for your hint.

I must change the session configuration:

```
// Session Configuration
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // correct initialization
});
```